# ASP.Net Core 2.1 with Angular Template - Cannot update Bootstrap

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

When I create a new ASP.Net Core 2.1 project, pick the angular template, go into package.json and change the version number of bootstrap from the default version 3 to version 4 ("4.0.0" etc..) then it always breaks my application. I have tried so many things such as deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling it and trying to update all of bootstrap's other dependencies but no luck.

I want to be able to update it to version 4.0 so that I can follow the code examples on the bootstrap homepage.

Doing this breaks the routing in angular so no page loads and produces the following `BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major` error. I have tried updating browserslist but no luck.

Has anyone else tried creating a new project in VS 2017 and picking the "ASP.Net Core 2.1 with Angular" template and then attempted to update bootstrap? Is there a "proper" way of doing this?

```
webpack: Failed to compile.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices:Error: ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
    at error (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
    at Function.browserslist.checkName (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:320:18)
    at Function.select (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
    at C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at browserslist (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
    at Browsers.parse (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:44:14)
    at new Browsers (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:39:28)
    at loadPrefixes (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:56:18)
    at plugin (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:62:18)
    at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:277:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:192:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:231:20)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
 @ multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
    at error (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
    at Function.browserslist.checkName (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:320:18)
    at Function.select (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
    at C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at browserslist (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
    at Browsers.parse (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:44:14)
    at new Browsers (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:39:28)
    at loadPrefixes (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:56:18)
    at plugin (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:62:18)
    at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:277:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:192:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:231:20)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:195:19)
    at C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:364:11
    at C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:230:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.catch (C:\Users\Anon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\lib\index.js:189:71)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a specific beta version of bootstrap **without the ^ modifier:**

`"bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",`

I hope this helps someone else who comes across this issue!

Hopefully, the developers will get this fixed soon.